# How do I use the Xcode comparison function？

Tags: xcode

I succeed before, but what's the problem now?
It reminds me "File was added", but how do I add an old version file to the right blank and comparing it with the left?
Thanks.
[picture displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OE1nX.png)

Comment: Has the file some older (checked in!) versions in the repository?

Comment: I don't understand, why I need another file older versions in the repository?  I just want to compare the local state and saved state of this file.

Answer (score 1):

The comparison tool is only available for files that are under source control. Clicking the clock symbol will give the timeline with commits to select the versions for each side; you might want to pick one from directly below the editor as well.